# What Wordpress function to use to get meta value by using meta keys?

Tags: functions, custom-field, post-meta, meta-value

This is the code:

```
if ($keys = get_post_custom_keys()) {
    foreach ((array) $keys as $key) {
        $keyt = trim($key);
        if (is_protected_meta($keyt, 'post')) {
            continue;
        }

        $values = array_map('trim', 
        get_post_custom_values($key));
        $value = implode($values, ', ');
        echo " key : ".$key;
        echo " value : ".$value;
    }
}
```

The Result:

```
keyyy : nova_price valueee : $9
```

My question: Is there a specific Wordpress function to get the meta value `$9` using meta key `nova price`?

I tried using this WP function:

```
echo" get_post_meta: "; get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'nova_price', true);
```

but the result is:

```
get_post_meta: 1872
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: Try using `get_the_ID()` instead of `the_ID()` in your `get_post_meta()`. `the_ID()` echoes in the post id directly, and hence the number 1872.

So it should be `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nove_price', true)`

Comment: Thanks, I did use  `get_the_ID()` but it returned nothing [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/6gRLVZyBJn7m), which is weird.

Comment: If I use `the_ID()` this was the [result](https://www.screencast.com/t/TMgNq6KfE)

Comment: Try `var_dump( get_theID() );` just before your `get_post_meta();` call and check if it returns the correct post id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the solution suggested in comments worked out for you, I'll just post that as answer over here.

You need to replace `the_ID()` function in your `get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'nova_price', true);` call.

Because `the_ID()` directly outputs the post ID which is then getting printed for you instead of the meta.

Right code would be:
`get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nova_price', true)`
This should get you the value for *nova_price* for the given post.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was really my stupid mistake. Somehow, I was too focused on get_post_meta(). Upon checking the WP code reference, I began to realize that it wasn't the wrapper's problem `get_post_meta()`, when this worked:

```
get_metadata('post', 1874, 'nova_price', true);
```

So the problem is this:

```
echo" get_post_meta: ";  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nova_price', true);
```

It should have been like this:

```
echo" get_post_meta: ". get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nova_price', true);
```

A minor problem that I overlooked. At least now, I know the 2-functions in getting the value by meta key in WP.  Again, many thanks for the effort & help.